# SQL to find highest value for repeated records

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have scenario like this.

```
ID| NAME|   EMAIL
---|------|--------------|---
11| ROCKY|  ROCKY@XYZ.COM
99| JAMES|  JAMES@XYZ.COM
88| ROCKY|  ROCKY@XYZ.COM
77| JAMES|  JAMES@XYZ.COM
```

My expected result is

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
99   ROCKY  ROCKY@XYZ.COM
88   JAMES  JAMES@XYZ.COM
```

Please help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Are you sure that is your expected result? Shouldn't it be 99 James and 88 Rocky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide your SQL statement I can only guess what you are trying to do.

Did you try?

```
ORDER BY ID desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my colleague has used select distinct(id) which is wrong because highest id should be picked for each repeated name/email id, so i will try your option, thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

I think your expected result has a typo. But I think what you want is a simple `group by`:

```
select name, email, max(id)
from yourtable
group by name, email
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my colleague has used select distinct(id) which is wrong because highest id should be picked for each repeated name/email id, so i will try your option, thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MSSQL and your expected result is the exact opposite of what you posted, you'll want to use the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), NAME, EMAIL FROM YourTable GROUP BY NAME, EMAIL
```

Comment: Actually the syntax used is so basic it should work on every rdbms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my colleague has used select distinct(id) which is wrong because highest id should be picked for each repeated name/email id, so i will try your option, thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Codeulike would be my first choice  +1

But another Option is using the WITH TIES clause

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,NAME varchar(50),EMAIL varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(11,'ROCKY','ROCKY@XYZ.COM'),
(99,'JAMES','JAMES@XYZ.COM'),
(88,'ROCKY','ROCKY@XYZ.COM'),
(77,'JAMES','JAMES@XYZ.COM')

Select Top 1 with Ties *
 From  @YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Name,EMail Order by ID Desc)
```

Returns

```
ID  NAME    EMAIL
99  JAMES   JAMES@XYZ.COM
88  ROCKY   ROCKY@XYZ.COM
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, my colleague has used select distinct(id) which is wrong because highest id should be picked for each repeated name/email id, so i will try your option, thanks a ton